# Printing a long long int as int outputs negative value

Tags: c, casting, int, printf

Why does this simple C program print `-2147483648`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("%i", (int)2147483648);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course if I don't cast it and use `%lld` as the format specifier I get the expected output.

Comment: You read https://www.hackerschool.com/blog/5-learing-c-with-gdb didn't you? I read it 5 minutes ago and paused for a minute at the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting an integer to a smaller signed type, the behavior is implementation-defined if the value cannot be represented in the new type:

> 6.3.1.3
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an
>   implementation-deﬁned signal is raised.

Comment: Where can I read about the "defined" behaviour?

Comment: Only if it overflows, this is fine: `(int) (unsigned long long) 3`.

Comment: @nightcracker Good call, fixed the wording.

Answer (score 3):

2147483647 is the maximum value of `int` on your platform.

2147483648 == 0x80000000 has the same binary representation as -2147483648, that's why you got that result.

Answer (score 0):

When you cast to an `int`, you are (at least on your current platform) casting to a 32-bit signed number. The largest postive value that can be stored in that space is 2147483647. When you add 1, you roll over to the largest negative value, which is the output.

When you use `long long int`, I believe the minimum width is 64-bit. You can easily hold the value 2147483648 in that space, so the output is as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

On a 32-bit two's complement system  the maximum `int` is usually:

```
2147483647
```

so

```
2147483648
```

is a `long` value.

The conversion of a value to a signed type when the value cannot fit in the signed type is implementation-defined.